# Save as binary file in C but it doesn't display zeros and ones

Tags: c, file, struct, binary, fopen

As i do understand, by saving a file in C using wb mode, shouldn't I see binary numbers in the saved files (zeros and ones).

When I save in wb mode the output in the file is:

> Feras Wilson    —   n      FFFF  îè`         c P   xHF   F
>   û¥2012

But this is not binary zeros and ones. How do I save file to contain zeros and ones and then be able to read It in C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is saved as 0 and 1, but your text editor reads them as bytes (it groups them in 8 bits) and displays them using ASCII. [1]

When you write to a text file, a lot of effort is done in order to interpret the binary data that you wish to write so it is put in a human readable format.

For example if you write the number `255`, it would have to bring it to the form `'2'`, `'5'`, `'5'` (which are characters! ) and then write these each character.

If it writes to a binary file, it will just put in the file the actually binary data. This depends on what kind of variable it is ( on how many octets is it represent it on ) and on endianess and other things. If it is an unsigned char it will put in the binary file `0b11111111` ( which is the actual raw number, not characters!).

[1] http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 5):

This is only the textual representation of the file by your editor or command. Internally all files are stored with 0s and 1s on the HDD/SDD/RAM/... - try opening the file with a hex editor like `bless` (easy to use on linux, Mono required for Windows - alternatively search for another Hex Editor you want to use) to see how the bytes are stored. Furthermore I suggest using `bless` because if offers different representations in different formats.

In your code, you can use the read methods to store the content bytewise and interpret this. Just keep a possible [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) fix in mind if you read more than one byte at a time. That is that Little and Big Endian systems store and read bytes in "reversed" order. A word `0x1337` being read could possibly be read as `0x3713`. Just get familiar with this term and use Wikipedia to understand how to handle this, if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

All files are stored in binary! It's just a question of how a successive program views/interprets this binary. Depending on how you use this file, it'll get read as a sequence of bytes representing chararacters, or a sequence of bytes representing instructions, or words representing Unicode etc. etc.

If you want to see your file in different formats, use [`od`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?od):

> NAME
>
> ```
>    od - dump files in octal and other formats
> ```

which will dump your file in hex, characters, octal etc. (the one thing it won't do is show you in binary, but you can derive that from the octal/hex output easily enough)